# Swift: Добавить элемент на UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Есть UICollectionView, в каждой ячейке - картинка. У меня есть кнопка "Редактировать", после нажатия на которую при тапе по ячейке она удаляется. Но для большей очевидности хотелось бы добавлять после нажатия на "Редактировать" маленькую картинку-маркер, но я не могу понять как обновить уже сгенерированные ячейки.

Пробовал вот такой вариант, но тогда маркер добавляется исключительно на первую ячейку, в независимости от числа после at, что меня вообще ставит в тупик:

```swift
let marker = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage(named: "delete_photo"))
marker.frame = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3 - 35, y: 10, width: 25, height: 25)
self.albumView.insertSubview(marker, at: 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте этот маркер на Вашу `UICollectionView`, сделайте его скрытым (`isHidden = true`).

При смене режима (когда нажимается кнопка редактировать), перезагружаете `UICollectionView` и устанавливаете для маркера `isHidden = false` в методе dataSource `collectionView(_:,cellForItemAt:)`.

После окончания редактирования снова устанавливаете маркеру в ячейках `isHidden = true`.

Comment: Спасибо!) Это помогло)